# Why should I clear my browser cache? I updated a page but can't see the changes

Tags: browser-cache, updating

I updated my page and I can't see the changes if I won't clear my browser cache.
So people were not seeing the change. Then the thought came that they need to clear their cache. But how can I force a browser to clear its cache when it visits my website?

Comment: It is a Chrome bug. The only thing you can do is to redirect it to something with GET param, like `http://mypage.com/?something`, and then check if something is defined. If it is, then go with page content.

Comment: @FlashThunder Browser caching is a bug?

Comment: @Juhana Ignoring all nocache directives is a bug.

Comment: @FlashThunder There is no indication in the question that there are nocache directives at all.

Comment: @Juhana It doesn't matter. Server sends headers that content have been modified.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a Chrome bug isn't an issue here, and I'm almost certain the bug isn't that severe.

Comment: Probably you are right, thats why it is comment, not an answer :)

Comment: What's the right one ? @_@